# Getting error while dropping an item into treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, telerik, mvvm-light

I am using RadTreeView from Telerik's Silverlight RadControls.  My XAML for the RadTreeView is below:

```xml
       <telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="treeView1" IsDragDropEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,444,0" ItemsSource="{Binding SectionList}">
           <telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Name="defaultSectionName" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Question1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadTreeView>
        <telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="treeView2" IsDragDropEnabled="True" Margin="410,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedSectionList}" >
            <telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Name="SelectedSectionName" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Question1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:RadTreeView>
```

I have fire events like below:

```
  private void OnDropQuery(object sender, DragDropQueryEventArgs e)
    {

            RadTreeViewItem destinationItem = e.Options.Destination as RadTreeViewItem;
            object source = this.GetItemFromPayload<object>(e.Options.Payload);
            object target = destinationItem != null ? destinationItem.Item : null;
            DropPosition position = destinationItem != null ? destinationItem.DropPosition : DropPosition.Inside;

            if (source != null && target != null)
            {
                Section sourceSection = source as Section;
                Section targetSection = target as Section;
                Question sourceQuestion = source as Question;
                Question targetQuestion = target as Question;

                if (sourceSection != null)
                {
                    e.QueryResult = false;
                    return;
                }

                if (sourceQuestion != null)
                {
                    if (sourceQuestion != null && targetQuestion != null && object.ReferenceEquals(sourceQuestion, targetQuestion))
                    {
                        e.QueryResult = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    if (targetQuestion != null && position == DropPosition.Inside)
                    {
                        e.QueryResult = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    if (position != DropPosition.Inside && targetQuestion == null)
                    {
                        e.QueryResult = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.QueryResult = false;
                return;
            }
            e.QueryResult = true;

    }

    private T GetItemFromPayload<T>(object payload)
    {
            IEnumerable draggedItems = payload as IEnumerable;
            if (draggedItems != null)
            {
                return draggedItems.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
            }

        return default(T);
    }
```

But when I am trying to drop Question I get a NullReferenceException. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You haven't provided all of your code.  Presumably you have Section and Question view-model classes - what do they contain?  How is the `OnDropQuery` handler wired up?  Where is this `OnDropQuery` method - is it, for example, in the code-behind of a UserControl that contains the treeviews?

Comment: OnDropQuery is in code behind of childWindow . The section class contains the different type of sections like: food section....etc. the question class contains perticular section wise questions Like: Is food is fresh? etc... The onDropQuery is called in a Constructor like:                 `public MainWindow() { this.treeView1.AddHandler(RadDragAndDropManager.DropQueryEvent, new EventHandler<DragDropQueryEventArgs>(OnDropQuery), true);
                this.treeView2.AddHandler(RadDragAndDropManager.DropQueryEvent, new EventHandler<DragDropQueryEventArgs>(OnDropQuery), true); } `

Comment: You still haven't provided enough details for me to be able to reproduce your error.  Where is the code for your `Section` and `Question` classes?  (If it happens that the bug is in one of them, you're not helping us.)  Also, can you post the stacktrace of the NullReferenceException you're getting?  Finally, please avoid posting too much code in comments; instead, edit your question to add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I just put this code in try catch block and changed the code:

```
if (sourceQuestion != null && targetQuestion != null && object.ReferenceEquals(sourceQuestion, targetQuestion))
                    {
                        sourceSection.Questions.Remove(sourceQuestion);
                        targetSection.Questions.Add(sourceQuestion);
                        e.QueryResult = false;
                        return;
                    }
```

This is it. It is working.